# Multer diskStorage callback not invoked within node express

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using multer for file upload with `diskStorage`. The `destination` and `filename` callbacks are not invoked apparently. Express

```
app.post(self._options.baseUrl + '/upload',
                function (req, res, next) {
                    var req_start = new Date().getTime();
                    var upload = multer({
                        storage: multer.diskStorage({
                            destination: function (req, file, callback) {
                                const tempdir = os.tmpdir();
                                self.logger.debug(`audio dir: ${tempdir}`);
                                callback(null, tempdir);
                            },
                            filename: function (req, file, callback) {
                                const originalName = encodeURIComponent(path.parse(file.originalname).name).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
                                const timestamp = Date.now()
                                const extension = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()
                                const filename = originalName + '_' + timestamp + extension;
                                self.logger.debug(`audio: ${filename}`);
                                callback(null, filename);
                            }
                        }),
                        fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
                            const acceptableExtensions = ['mp3', 'mp4']
                            if (!(acceptableExtensions.some(extension =>
                                path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase() === `.${extension}`)
                            )) {
                                var message = createErrorMessage(500, '', '', 'audio type not valid');
                                res.send(message);
                                return callback(res.send(message), null)
                            }
                            return callback(null, true);
                        },
                        limits: {
                            fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
                        }
                    }).single('file');
                    upload(req, res, function (error) {
                        if (error instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                            var message = createErrorMessage(500, '', '', 'audio upload error');
                            res.send(message);
                        } else if (error) {
                            var message = createErrorMessage(500, '', '', 'audio not valid');
                            res.send(message);
                        }
                        res.end('OK');
                    });
                });
```

It seems that the `multer.diskStorage` is not being called here.